# Connectivity issues on university network

Tags: mac, arch-linux

I try to connect to an University network using archlinux and wicd. I can't give too many details about the network itself, but it is somehow mac-related (basically you register your mac and the connection is based on that). On windows it works flawlessly, but on linux there are some issues. At the beginning, I could connect to the network, but I couldn't receive packets (100% packet loss at ping). I have spoken to the network team and they gave me a static ip. Now, I can connect from linux using that static ip, but there is an interesting issue: if I just boot on linux and connect, 100% packet loss on ping (this includes ping to the gateway). In order to make it work, I have to boot on windows (the connection is established automatically, I didn't do any setup), then boot into archlinux. And it works.

My guess is that there is a sort of "registration" on network, that is made automatically on windows but not on linux. The mac address is the same on both operating systems. How can I make it work from linux?

Comment: Arch Linux.... good luck bro. Good luck.

Comment: Is it an [eduroam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) network?